# UAC in Metro style app (VS 2012)

Tags: styles, microsoft-metro, uac

I want my app always run as administrator. I already created new manifest file (via New Items -> Manifest file), put requestedExecutionLevel as "requireAdministrator", but it doesn't ask for credentials at all, even when i try it on another non-administrator account (instal via appackages). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows store applications cannot be run as 'elevated'. They are run inside an app container, which restricts the permissions even further than a normal user.